# Can I get separate output on retasked jacks?

Tags: audio, audio-conversion, realtek-hd-audio

I'm using realtek audio console, and I've retasked my mic jack to speaker output. I wanted to have two separate output(2nd output), but instead I got only one, and 2nd output activates only when front and back panel is connected, not 2 on the back.

Is there a way to have 2 outputs when 2 jacks are connected on the back?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to assign one as line-out  and the other as headphone. If you want both outputs to also play audio at the same time, you may have to set a setting to do that. Otherwise, get a splitter cable.

Comment: @LPChip I want to activate only one output, but the two of them outputs the same... and I couldn't assign one as lineout and other as headphone, currently two ports are assigned as line out.